# best way to handle same field value comparison in single object - React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a category item which has the ability to be a child of another category. This also means a child can have children of its own.

The thinking was to say if isChild, compare parent to all id's and return the match.

Schema item looks like so

```
id: ID!
name: String
isChild: Boolean
parent: String
createdAt: AWSDateTime
updatedAt: AWSDateTime
```

In React I tried something like this just to return the items,

```
{categories.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <>
        {item.isChild !== true ? (
          <h3 key={index}>
          {item.name}
          </h3>
        ) : (
          <>
          {categories.map((subItem) => {
            return (
              <>
              {subItem.parent === item.id && (
                <p>
                  {item.name}
                </p>
              )}
              </>
            )
          })}
          </>
        )}
        </>
      )
    })}
```

Though not ideal, this gives me the **ITEM** and the correct *subItem*. The problem is, I need to be able to go ITEM -> subItem -> subItem -> etc. until no more matches.

As for the function, end users need to be able to perform basic CRUD operations. UI is a card essentially. Each category item gets their own card with accordion to show children.

Comment: What do you mean by "ITEM -> subItem -> subItem -> etc." Does a child also have its own children? If so, you might be able to solve this with a recursive function. Also, you should provide more context so that we can understand what you are trying to do. What do you want the actual UI to look like and to do?

Comment: Exactly, A child can have its own children. I will update

Answer (score 0):

I suggest changing your data structure. Instead of an array of objects with `parent` and `isChild` attributes, use a tree structure directly. One way to do this is with a Java object. Something like this:

```
id: ID!
name: String
children:  [Item]
createdAt: AWSDateTime
updatedAt: AWSDateTime
```

Ideally you should start with this structure to begin with. If for some reason you can't, such as because you are getting data from a REST API that you have no control over, then you can transform the array to such an object using `reduce()` instead of `map()`. You might need to make this in a named function so that you can call it recursively.

Comment: This was the original thought, however it was changed to the above because of editing. Am I just having a brain fart here. But if a user edits the item to say no longer be a child would this not work?

Comment: What do you mean by "edits the item to say no longer be a child"? How does the user do that? What does the UI look like for editing? Do you have a control that allows the user to edit the `isChild` field directly? If you no longer have an `isChild` field, then such a control no longer makes any sense. You could instead allow the user to drag and drop items to move them? (Ok, that is probably pretty complicated to implement...but definitely would be better UX than most alternatives.) However the UI looks, if you allow the user to move items around, you just move them within the data structure.

Comment: UI is currently being re-done anyways, it was just inputs and a select for the boolean.